# Unix command that takes no arguments

Tags: command-line

Don't ask why, but is there a Unix command that takes no arguments?

Comment: Are you looking for a command that would error if given arguments, or that just don't process their arguments?  I'm not immediately thinking of any in the former category (though one would be easy to create, and they may well exist), but the latter category has various examples.  And of course there are *many* unix commands that do something useful without any arguments, but I'm *guessing* that's not what you're asking.

Comment: I can't help myself. Why? :P

Comment: Without further explanation what the issue is, whether "arguments" means options or operands or both, or why the question is asked in the first place, the question is unclear and too broad.

Answer (score 4):

`true` and `false` are two examples.

Or did you mean commands that take no options?  I can't think of any, but the original Unix version of `echo` didn't take any options.  There's even a [story](http://everything2.com/title/The+UNIX+and+the+Echo) about it how it came to take options.

Comment: `yes` is another one.

Comment: @asoundmove `yes` doesn't _require_ an argument, but it does accept/use one.

Comment: As is so often the case, this largely depends on what Unix implementation you are using. Yes, POSIX doesn't specify any arguments for `true`, but that doesn't stop the GNU project: `true --help` yields
`Aufruf: /bin/true NAME
 oder:  /bin/true OPTION
Aufruf: %s [ignorierte Kommandzeilen-Argument]
 oder:  %s OPTION
Mit einem Status-Code beenden, der erfolgreiche Ausführung signalisiert.` (21 lines total.) You'll notice that it is even localized!

Answer (score 3):

If you accidentally run `docker ps a` (instead of `docker ps -a`) you'll actually get a message:

**"docker ps" accepts no arguments.**

Kinda reminds me of my wife.

Comment: upvoted for the wife comment. Funny.

Answer (score 2):

`nologin` takes no arguments and is widely available on Linux and BSD.

On CentOS 4 and 5, the `arch` command takes no arguments. On other linux distros, arch is now provided by GNU coreutils which takes --version and --help. With CentOS 4 and 5 it comes from util-linux which differs from GNU's version.

A lot of the things in GNU coreutils take only --help and --version, if you look at different Unixes that don't use GNU coreutils, they don't accept any arguments: `sync`, `true`, `false`, `whoami`, `pwd`, `groups`, `users`

Answer (score 2):

`:`, `true`, `false`, `reset`, `clear`, `line`, `chkdupexe` and `arch` all take no arguments.

I'm sure they accept them, but they ignore them.

Comment: OMG.. true and false are commands!... must try this: true; echo $? ... 0 | false; echo $? ... 1 ... yup! ... an ineresting bit if info... bash **is** different :)